# Vuetify v-data-table drag and resizable columns together

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify v-data-table. I implement drag column with SortableJs and also column resizable.

When I drag a column, it works properly but after that the resize does not work anymore.

```
<div id="app">
 <v-app id="inspire">
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts"
                sort-by="calories" 
                disable-sort
                v-sortable-table="{onEnd:sortTheHeadersAndUpdateTheKey}"
                :key="anIncreasingNumber" >

  </v-data-table>
 </v-app>
</div>
```

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoeko/pen/gOwmjbE?editors=1010)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3278), the Vuetify team is not interested in doing this feature now.

> Thank you for the Feature Request and interest in improving Vuetify. Unfortunately, this is not a functionality we are looking to implement now.

For now, you can check this [CodepPen](https://codepen.io/crwilson311/pen/Bajbdwd?editors=0010) it will do the trick for you.
If you don't want to do it manually you could install an npm package called [vue-columns-resizable-vuetify](https://npm.io/package/vue-columns-resizable-vuetify)

```html
<!-- Credit 
Column Resize - Web Dev Tricks https://webdevtrick.com/resizable-table-columns/
Vuetify Datatable - Vuetify Example
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/ -->

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```css
th, td {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', sortable: false, value: 'name'},
        { text: 'Calories', sortable: false, value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', sortable: false, value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', sortable: false, value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', sortable: false, value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', sortable: false, value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var i=0; i<tables.length;i++){
 resizableGrid(tables[i]);
}

function resizableGrid(table) {
 var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0],
 cols = row ? row.children : undefined;
 if (!cols) return;
 
 table.style.overflow = 'hidden';
 
 var tableHeight = table.offsetHeight;
 
 for (var i=0;i<cols.length;i++){
  var div = createDiv(tableHeight);
  cols[i].appendChild(div);
  cols[i].style.position = 'relative';
  setListeners(div);
 }

 function setListeners(div){
  var pageX,curCol,nxtCol,curColWidth,nxtColWidth;

  div.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
   curCol = e.target.parentElement;
   nxtCol = curCol.nextElementSibling;
   pageX = e.pageX; 
 
   var padding = paddingDiff(curCol);
 
   curColWidth = curCol.offsetWidth - padding;
   if (nxtCol)
    nxtColWidth = nxtCol.offsetWidth - padding;
  });

  div.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
   e.target.style.borderRight = '2px solid #0000ff';
  })

  div.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
   e.target.style.borderRight = '';
  })

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
   if (curCol) {
    var diffX = e.pageX - pageX;
 
    if (nxtCol)
     nxtCol.style.width = (nxtColWidth - (diffX))+'px';

    curCol.style.width = (curColWidth + diffX)+'px';
   }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) { 
   curCol = undefined;
   nxtCol = undefined;
   pageX = undefined;
   nxtColWidth = undefined;
   curColWidth = undefined
  });
 }
 
 function createDiv(height){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.top = 0;
  div.style.right = 0;
  div.style.width = '5px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
  div.style.userSelect = 'none';
  div.style.height = height + 'px';
  return div;
 }
 
 function paddingDiff(col){
 
  if (getStyleVal(col,'box-sizing') == 'border-box'){
   return 0;
  }
 
  var padLeft = getStyleVal(col,'padding-left');
  var padRight = getStyleVal(col,'padding-right');
  return (parseInt(padLeft) + parseInt(padRight));

 }

 function getStyleVal(elm,css){
  return (window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue(css))
 }
};
```